# How do i maintain order of selected files in javafx multi file chooser

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to implement a multiple file selection feature in my program where the order a user selects these files really matters.
Currently what I'm doing is storing the selected files in a list of files so as to loop through and process them individually, however, the files get sorted by default in ascending order. Is there a way to go about this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible using only one file chooser. A workarround would be to let the user select only [one file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html#showOpenDialog-javafx.stage.Window-) and open another file chooser after the file was selected (and probably [set the initial directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html#setInitialDirectory-java.io.File-) so the user doesn't have to find the path again)

Comment: Alryt, thank you! . will try that..

Comment: @nyel Consider a naming convention like 1.First File or A First File OR put them in a ComboBox and once the file is selected cboSelect.getItems().remove(A First File)